# In C#, how can i add a null check into dynamic express code

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

i am leveraging [this project to use jqgrid to filter and sort collections](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx).  The one issue i see if that, when looping through the collection and checking the property of a string field is null, this code below will blow up.  i want to tweak the code below so it creates a lambda that not only does a "ToString()" and "Contains" but also support if a property is null (and treats it as string.empty)

I basically have 2 inputs into this function below:

1. FieldName
2. Data Value

and the code below is dynamically building up an expression to loop through a collection and check "Contains" against the property that maps onto the FieldName being passed in.

i have code that looks like this:

```
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

        MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
        MethodCallExpression memberAccessToString = null;
        foreach (var property in column.Split('.'))
        {
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property(memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);
            memberAccessToString = MemberExpression.Call(memberAccess, "ToString", new Type[] {}, new Expression[] {});
        }

        Expression condition = null;
        LambdaExpression lambda = null;
            case WhereOperation.Contains:
                condition = Expression.Call(memberAccessToString,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    Expression.Constant(value));
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);

        MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
               typeof(Queryable), "Where",
               new[] { query.ElementType },
               query.Expression,
               lambda);

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
```

Comment: `this code below will blow up` Can you specify where it blows up what the exception is when it blows up?

Comment: @Bala R - when the lambda actually runs against the collection i get "object not set to instance of . . ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked `Expression.Coalesce` you could apply it to memberAccess before calling **ToString()**

```
memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property(memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);
memberAccessToString = MemberExpression.Call(Expression.Coalesce(memberAccess,Expression.Constant(string.Empty)), "ToString", new Type new Type[] {}, new Expression[] {});
```

Didn't test it but may lead to the solution

Comment: i tried this and it worked on string fields but now it causes errors with fields that are not strings.  i get this error: "Argument types do not match".           Here is the exact line that i added: memberAccessToString = MemberExpression.Call(Expression.Coalesce(memberAccess, Expression.Constant(string.Empty)), "ToString", new Type[] {}, new Expression[] {});

Comment: Since you mentioned that you wanted your property treated as string.Empty I assumed all your properties were strings. If that's not the case you should add a Cast to object so both elements of coalesce have the same type.

Comment: Here is the code. `memberAccessToString = MemberExpression.Call(Expression.Coalesce(Expression.Convert(memberAccess,typeof(object)), Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(string.Empty),typeof(object))), "ToString", new Type[] {}, new Expression[] {});`