# Building expression to check for null

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm having trouble to figure out how to build an expression tree to determine if a property is null.  I've got something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<S, bool>> CreateFunc(QueryPiece<S> queryPc)
{
    //arg
    ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S));

    //property
    MemberExpression memberExpr = Expression.Property(argParam, "SomeProperty");

    //property type for constant conversion
    Type propType = memberExpr.Member is MethodInfo
        ? ((MethodInfo)memberExpr.Member).ReturnType
        : ((PropertyInfo)memberExpr.Member).PropertyType;

    //tried this ... unsuccessfully
    Expression func = Expression.Equal(memberExpr, Expression.Constant(null, propType));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<S, bool>>(func, argParam);
}
```

My hope - however vain  ;-) - was that I could just as if the member property was equivalent to null.

I've seen some mentions of how this might be accomplished using Expression.Coalesce, but I can't seem to get it to work.  For the record, the runtime error thrown when I try to use the returned Lambda is a generic ArgumentNullException.

I've found this similar post: [In C#, how can i add a null check into dynamic express code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608521/in-c-how-can-i-add-a-null-check-into-dynamic-express-code)  - I just can't seem to out how to refactor it for my scenario.

Comment: Your code works for me. The problem resulting in an `ArgumentNullException` most likely lies elsewhere. Please show the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - oh my gosh, how embarrassing - the error was unrelated.  Thanks for pushing me back into the stack trace.